# Is "where" possible to use in delete() in firestore? I am looking for a way to delete ranged documents

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a way to delete certain data from firestore.

For example, I would like to wipe out documents that include "OVER" in 'name' field.
I tried to do this code. but it does not work.
How should I do?

```
    firebase
    .firestore().collection("stack").where("name",">=","OVER").delete().then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have the concept of update or delete queries, where you send a condition to the server and it updates/deletes the relevant documents. You will have to:

1. Execute the query.
2. Loop over the results.
3. Delete each document.